# How to update the state when navigating back in Jetpack Compose

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, objectbox

How can I ensure that the list of feedList in my first screen updates after adding a new feed item on the second screen? I'm using a navController to navigate between the two screens and ObjectBox as my database.

In my app, the first screen displays a list of feeds, and the second screen allows me to add a new feed item. When I add a new feed item on the second screen and return to the first screen, the list does not include the newly added item. I suspect that the function viewModel.onGetFeedList() is not being executed at the appropriate time also it is inside the LaunchedEffect.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    vm.composeViewModel.onGetFeedList()
    vm.composeViewModel.getFeedCollectionList()
}
```

To provide some context, I'm using ObjectBox as my database and have set up the necessary entities, DAOs, and a ViewModel to handle the data operations.

```
  fun saveSingleRecord(modal: Feed): Long {
            val obj = box().query(Feed_.mId.equal(modal.mId)).build()?.findUnique()
            if (obj == null) {
                box().put(modal)
                return 1
            } else {
    
                obj.mId = modal.mId
                obj.name = modal.name
                obj.nepaliName = modal.nepaliName
                obj.DMPercent = modal.DMPercent
                obj.MEOrMIPerKg = modal.MEOrMIPerKg
                obj.DCPPerKg = modal.DCPPerKg
                obj.NDFPercent = modal.NDFPercent
                obj.CaPerGram = modal.CaPerGram
                obj.PPerGram = modal.PPerGram
                obj.concentrate = modal.concentrate
                obj.price = modal.price
                obj.categoryId = modal.categoryId
                obj.SN = modal.SN
    
                box().put(obj)
    
                Logger.log("AFTER EDIT = ${GsonUtils.toString(obj)}")
                return 2
            }
        }
```

I would like to know where and when I should execute viewModel.onGetFeedList() to ensure that the first screen displays the updated list of feeds after returning from the second screen. Could you please guide me on the correct approach to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please put your dao and LaunchedEffect code .

Comment: @HanifShaikh, I have added. Please have a look!

Comment: @SrijanKhadka, Did you tried using Coroutine Flow? I think you can solve the issue by using Flow

Comment: @SrijanKhadka you are not put your dao yet.

Comment: @SrijanKhadka do you have the same viewmodel for the listfeed screen and the add feed screen or they are separate

Comment: If you need to observe for changes, you should expose the data from the ViewModel using Flow. Fetching data is not a single event in your case, so it should be collected in the Composable rather than calling a method from LaunchedEffect.

Comment: @AymanAit different viewmodel but common repository

Answer (score 0):

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    vm.composeViewModel.onGetFeedList()
    vm.composeViewModel.getFeedCollectionList()
}
```

put true instead of unit. I hope it's helps

Comment: This will work but its bad because when you provide true as a key to launched effect that means it will execute every time the recomposition happens and thats so bad for performance.